# How can I add non generated print- and download- buttons for reports with ReportViewer WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, reportviewer

Today we have course diplomas generated by ReportViewer (Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewer).

The toolbar looks like this [Toolbar with buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhUtW.png).
The Toolbar is generated by the ReportViewer. Is there any way to add my own buttons that have the same functionality?